# InvalidEntrypoint when running containerised lambda function with linux/amd64 base image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm on a OSX M1 chip. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I think I've built the image correctly with a linux/amd64 base image. I have the following files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.12

COPY main.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD ["main.handler"]
```

In the same directory as my Dockerfile I have a `main.py` with this:

```py
def handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    return event
```

I have the following lambda.tf file:

```
module "my_test_lambda" {

  source        = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version       = "4.17.0"
  function_name = local.deployment_prefix
  handler       = "main.handler"

  timeout     = 900
  memory_size = 1536

  # use_existing_cloudwatch_log_group       = true

  create_package = false

  package_type  = "Image"
  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  image_uri     = "1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-test-repo:latest"

  role_permissions_boundary = var.role_permissions_boundary_arn

  attach_policies    = true
  number_of_policies = 1

  policies = [
    aws_iam_policy.my-test-lambda.arn
  ]

  tags = {
    Component = local.module_name
  }
}
```

I'm running the following commands following login to ECR

```bash
docker build -t my-test-image .

docker tag my-test-image 1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-test-repo:latest

docker push 1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/sam-test-repo:latest
```

Then when I run the lambda via the console I get the following error:

> Status: error Error Type: Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
> Error: fork/exec /lambda-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
> Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've followed other answers in other questions but keep getting this error.

Comment: What value does `local.deployment_prefix` have?

Comment: development-my-test-lambda

Comment: Can you try with `handler       = "development-my-test-lambda.handler"`

Comment: if you want to add that as the answer i'll accept! Thanks a lot. Can't believe I missed 'development-my-test-lambda' right at the top of AWS Lambda console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a Lambda function, the `handler` consists of two parts:

1. Lambda function name
2. Handler name from the Lambda function code

By default, the naming convention is [`lambda_function.lambda_handler`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) for Python functions. In your case, the Lambda function name is defined with the `local.deployment_prefix` value, which means the function name has to be used instead of `main`. The name of the handler function in your code is `handler` (defined with `def handler`). In other words, what needs to be changed in terraform is the following:

```
module "my_test_lambda" {

  source        = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version       = "4.17.0"
  function_name = local.deployment_prefix
  handler       = "${local.deployment_prefix}.handler"

  timeout     = 900
  memory_size = 1536

  # use_existing_cloudwatch_log_group       = true

  create_package = false

  package_type  = "Image"
  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  image_uri     = "1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-test-repo:latest"

  role_permissions_boundary = var.role_permissions_boundary_arn

  attach_policies    = true
  number_of_policies = 1

  policies = [
    aws_iam_policy.my-test-lambda.arn
  ]

  tags = {
    Component = local.module_name
  }
}
```